# Can Client ID be pulled from the Google Analytics Reporting API V4?

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api

I've been sifting through how to get Client ID from google analytics APIs and it looks as if it is only available through the Multi-Channels Funnels Reporting API if you have an authenticated site.  It does not show in the Google Analytics Reporting API V4.

Does anyone know how to get this along with metrics and dimensions through an API without having an authenticated site?

Comment: You can't pull by **cid** as it would be a security issue, however, Google Measurement API provides a way to pull by hashed cid - [https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/clientId](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/clientId)

Answer (score 1):

[Dimensions & Metrics Explorer](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets) contains a full list of all dimensions and metrics that can be used with the [Reporting API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/).   The MCF API has a difference set of dimensions and metric which can be used with it those can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/mcf/dimsmets/).

That being said client id is not a dimension that can be extracted via the API .  The only option that I know if would be to add it as a custom dimension yourself then extracting that out.   You can extract [custom dimensions](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=custom_variables_or_columns) with the reporting API .

In any case you cant use the Reporting API without being authenticated you need to have access to private google analytics data.

Comment: actually, you CAN extract clientId from the API. Go try Google Anaytics addon for spreadsheet and manually add ga:clientId as a dimension. Anyways, adding it as a custom dimension is a better choice

Comment: The clientid dimension was added recently this anwser is two years old